# Highcharts navigator handle height

Tags: highcharts, navigator

Is there any way to increase the height of the handles in the highstock navigator component? Right now, the only options available are to change the color and the border-color. How about the height and width of the handles?

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#navigator.handles

Thanks,

Vikas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap `drawHandles` function and modify it to have increased height.

```
var height = 20; 

(function (H) {
    H.wrap(H.Scroller.prototype, 'drawHandle', function (proceed, x, index) {
        var scroller = this,
            chart = scroller.chart,
            renderer = chart.renderer,
            elementsToDestroy = scroller.elementsToDestroy,
            handles = scroller.handles,
            handlesOptions = scroller.navigatorOptions.handles,
            attr = {
                fill: handlesOptions.backgroundColor,
                stroke: handlesOptions.borderColor,
                    'stroke-width': 1
            },
            tempElem;

        // create the elements
        if (!scroller.rendered) {
            // the group
            handles[index] = renderer.g('navigator-handle-' + ['left', 'right'][index])
                .css({
                cursor: 'e-resize'
            })
                .attr({
                zIndex: 4 - index
            }) // zIndex = 3 for right handle, 4 for left
            .add();

            // the rectangle
            tempElem = renderer.rect(-4.5, 0, 9, height, 0, 1)
                .attr(attr)
                .add(handles[index]);
            elementsToDestroy.push(tempElem);

            // the rifles
            tempElem = renderer.path([
                'M', -1.5, 4,
                'L', -1.5, 12,
                'M',
            0.5, 4,
                'L',
            0.5, 12]).attr(attr)
                .add(handles[index]);
            elementsToDestroy.push(tempElem);
        }

        // Place it
        handles[index][chart.isResizing ? 'animate' : 'attr']({
            translateX: scroller.scrollerLeft + scroller.scrollbarHeight + parseInt(x, 10),
            translateY: scroller.top + scroller.height / 2 - 8
        });

    });
}(Highcharts));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/za68w54r/

Comment: Thank you so much Sebastian! Here's one issue though, when I increase the handle height to more than 20, the 2 lines inside it are still positioned towards the top. How do I adjust that? http://jsfiddle.net/Yrygy/303/

Comment: I the tempElem variable, there is renderer which print. Fixed example: http://jsfiddle.net/Yrygy/304/

Answer (score 2):

There is an option for increasing the height of the navigator too..

Check this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/navigator/height/

Code:

```
    navigator: {
        height: 100
    },
```

Comment: I was referring to the height of the handle in the selected time slice

Comment: Its not possible.. There are only options available for changing handles color and border-color.